# Universal type tranformer in Haskell

Tags: haskell, ghc

Logically, it's possible to define universal transformation function, that can transform from any type to any type.

The possible way is:

```
{-#LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-#LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

class FromTo a b where
    fromTo:: a->b

instance FromTo a a where fromTo = id

instance FromTo Int     Double where fromTo = fromIntegral
instance FromTo Int     Float  where fromTo = fromIntegral
instance FromTo Integer Double where fromTo = fromIntegral
instance FromTo Integer Float  where fromTo = fromIntegral

instance FromTo Double Int     where fromTo = round 
instance FromTo Double Integer where fromTo = round 
instance FromTo Float  Int     where fromTo = round 
instance FromTo Float  Integer where fromTo = round
-- e.t.c.
```

Well, it work's, it's extendable. But it's very bulky, because I must list any case I want to use.

**Is there any good solutions for this?**

---

The neat one solution could be done like this, if it was correct **(but it's not)**:

```
{-#LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-#LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-#LANGUAGE InstanceSigs #-}

class FromTo a b where
    fromTo:: a->b

instance (Integral a, Num b) => FromTo a b where
    fromTo::a->b
    fromTo x = (fromIntegral x)

{---Commented, because addition breaks program.-------------------------------
instance (RealFrac a, Integral b) => FromTo a b where
    fromTo::a->b
    fromTo x = (round x)
-}
```

Maybe it would be possible if there was some type sets extension (Haskell-like pseudo code):

```
{-#LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-#LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-#LANGUAGE InstanceSigs #-}
{-#LANGUAGE TypeSets #-}

class FromTo a b where
    fromTo:: a->b

instance setfrom (Integral a, Num b). (Integral a, Num b) => FromTo a b where
    fromTo::a->b
    fromTo x = (fromIntegral x)

instance setfrom (RealFrac a, Integral b). (RealFrac a, Integral b) => FromTo a b where
    fromTo::a->b
    fromTo x = (round x)
```

`setfrom C1 a.` here should define set of types, using instances information from `C1` class. The compiler should check if instances are intersects. The other possible construction of this extension is `set (T1,T2,...,TN) a.`, that allows to merely define the type set.

---

UPD 1

---

The 1-st solution could be improved this way (but it's **incorrect** way):

```
{-#LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-#LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}


class FromTo a b where
    fromTo:: a->b

instance FromTo a a where fromTo = id

instance Num b => FromTo Int b where
    fromTo x = fromIntegral x

instance Num b => FromTo Integer b where
    fromTo x = fromIntegral x

instance Integral b => FromTo Float b where
    fromTo x = round x

instance Integral b => FromTo Double b where
    fromTo x = round x
```

But it's still not good and, in addition, **gives overlaps** when calling in interactive mode:

```
*Main> fromTo (10::Double) ::Double

<interactive>:108:1:
    Overlapping instances for FromTo Double Double
      arising from a use of `fromTo'
    Matching instances:
      instance FromTo a a -- Defined at 4.hs:8:10
      instance Integral b => FromTo Double b -- Defined at 4.hs:19:10
    In the expression: fromTo (10 :: Double) :: Double
    In an equation for `it': it = fromTo (10 :: Double) :: Double
```

Answer (score 4):

From what I understand, you want to parameterize class instances by the constraints on the types. This is possible with modern GHC extensions:

```
{-#LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances, InstanceSigs, ConstraintKinds, 
  KindSignatures, DataKinds, TypeOperators, UndecidableInstances, GADTs #-}

import GHC.Prim(Constraint)


class ConstrainedBy (cons :: [* -> Constraint]) (t :: *) where

instance ConstrainedBy '[] t
instance (x t, ConstrainedBy xs t) => ConstrainedBy (x ': xs) t
```

The purpose of this class is to allow multiple constraints on a single type in the `FromTo` class. For example, you could decide that `Num a, Real a => Floating a` has a different instance than `Num a => Floating a` (this is a contrived example - but depending on your use cases, you may have need for this functionality).

Now we 'lift' this class to the data level with a GADT:

```
data ConsBy cons t where 
    ConsBy :: ConstrainedBy cons t => t -> ConsBy cons t 

instance Show t => Show (ConsBy cons t) where
    show (ConsBy t) = "ConsBy " ++ show t
```

Then, the `FromTo` class:

```
class FromTo (consa:: [* -> Constraint]) (a :: *) (consb :: [* -> Constraint]) (b :: *) where
    fromTo :: ConsBy consa a -> ConsBy consb b
```

I don't believe that there is a way to have the type that you specified for the function `fromTo`; if the type is simply `a -> b`, there is no way to deduce the constraints from the function arguments.

And your instances:

```
instance (Integral a, Num b) => FromTo '[Integral] a '[Num] b where
    fromTo (ConsBy x) = ConsBy (fromIntegral x)

instance (RealFrac a, Integral b) => FromTo '[RealFrac] a '[Integral] b where
    fromTo (ConsBy x) = ConsBy (round x)
```

You have to state all the constraints twice, unfortunately. Then:

```
>let x = ConsBy 3 :: Integral a => ConsBy '[Integral] a
>x
ConsBy 3
>fromTo x :: ConsBy '[Num] Float
ConsBy 3.0
```

You can have instances that would normally be considered 'overlapping':

```
instance (Integral a, Eq b, Num b) => FromTo '[Integral] a '[Num, Eq] b where
    fromTo (ConsBy x) = ConsBy (fromIntegral x + 1) -- obviously stupid

>let x = ConsBy 3 :: Integral a => ConsBy '[Integral] a
>fromTo x :: Num a => ConsBy '[Num] a
ConsBy 3
>fromTo x :: (Num a, Eq a) => ConsBy '[Num, Eq] a
ConsBy 4
```

On the other hand, if you wish to make the assertion that there is only one instance that can match a combination of type and constraints (making the above impossible), you can use functional dependencies to do this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-} 

class FromTo (consa:: [* -> Constraint]) (a :: *) (consb :: [* -> Constraint]) (b :: *) 
    | consa a -> consb b, consb b -> consa a
    where
      fromTo :: ConsBy consa a -> ConsBy consb b
```

Now the third instance that I wrote is invalid, however, you can use `fromTo` without explicit type annotations:

```
>let x = ConsBy 3 :: Integral a => ConsBy '[Integral] a
>fromTo x
ConsBy 3
>:t fromTo x
fromTo x
  :: Num b =>
     ConsBy ((':) (* -> Constraint) Num ('[] (* -> Constraint))) b
```

As you can see, the output type, `Num b => b`, is inferred from the input type. This works the same for polymorphic and concrete types:

```
>let x = ConsBy 3 :: ConsBy '[Integral] Int
>:t fromTo x
fromTo x
  :: Num b =>
     ConsBy ((':) (* -> Constraint) Num ('[] (* -> Constraint))) b
```

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use Template Haskell.  You'd still need to explicitly add all the types (instead of sets of types as typeclasses implies) but it would be shorter:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

-- ...

let x = mkName "x"
    list = [ (''Double, ''Int, 'floor)
           , (''Float,  ''Int, 'floor)
           ]
    mkI tyA tyB op = 
        instanceD
            (cxt [])
            (appT (appT (conT ''FromTo) (conT tyA)) (conT tyB))
            [ funD 'fromTo [clause [] (normalB iOp) []]
            , pragInlD 'fromTo Inline FunLike AllPhases
            ]
  in sequence [ mkI a b op | (a,b,op) <- list ]
```

With the above (untested) Template Haskell splice you can enumerate pairs of types and the operation for the conversion.  This still requires you to type `n choose 2` pairs into the list.

Alternatively, you could have a list of source types (tyA) and a separate list of target types (tyB) then convert between all the source types and all destination types - this strategy would be simple for similar types (all floats to all integrals) and save you some typing, but it isn't general enough for all conversions.

Comment: You might also go one step farther and look at `reify ''Integral` and `reify ''RealFrac` to get all the types you could use round with.

Comment: Yep, you can take the meta-programming much much farther than what I've done.